# How to ftp a file that is in use?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, file, winapi

- Uploading five `.txt` files from a directory on local machine with [PutFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67x0twby%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to another PC (running a ftp server).
- The last text file is currently opened by a process on my local machine (that periodically writes to it) but I still want to send it over.

When [FindNextFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gets to this file, is there a way to

1. Check that this is the "locked" file ([property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to check)?
   ->**EDIT** *PutFile fails with GetLastError() 0x32  sharing violation. This works for now to know that it is locked*
2. Unlock it?
3. or if I can't unlock it, just make a copy of it?

Thank You.

(C or C++ - Windows XP - Visual Studio .NET 2003)

**EDIT**

- The files have NOT been created by this process.

Comment: As u have told u r using MFC, but tag shows its winapi...I would recommend u to go with CreateFile function. If the handle is valid it means file is not locked. there's an article in C# but i think u can use it here as well http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/dead0507-06f5-43e0-9250-a78437956bc8/ 
I m not sure will winapi work with MFC coz I m unaware of it...

Comment: Thank you. This is correct, this is a windows console application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use volume shadow services to access an in use file

This [utility](https://github.com/candera/hobocopy/downloads) allows you to copy an in use file - there is also the source code so you can see how to do it inside your code

Comment: Thank You. Does this imply that windows will not allow this ?

Comment: Depending on how the other process has opened the file it can block you from reading it. There is an operating system function to copy the filesystem while it's in use eg for backup, called VSS. You can either call the utlilty to make a temp copy of the file for your app - or dig into the source and see how they do it